# Mover lista de arquivos entre pastas

Tags: java, arquivo, java-8

Tenho um método que copia arquivos de uma pasta para outra, deletando o arquivo em seguida. Até me atende perfeitamente, mas gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de se fazer isso sem precisar recorrer a `InputStream` e `OutputStream`, pois já tive alguns problemas com escrita utilizando estas classes.

Vi que no java 8 há funções que facilitam operações com arquivos utilizando a classe `Files`. É possível fazer essa operação de "mover arquivos" de forma mais simples e direta, utilizando outros métodos, como por exemplo, a classe `Files`?

Segue o código atual:

```
private static void copiarArquivos() throws IOException {

    File src = new File(".");
    String dstPath = "C:\\java\\";
    File dst;

    File[] files = src.listFiles();

    for (File f : files) {
        String fileName = f.getName();

        if (fileName.contains("File")) {

            dst = new File(dstPath + fileName);
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
            f.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Não sei se quer saber alguma coisa específica, mas em qualquer Java dá para fazer melhor que isso se quer apenas mover os arquivos, pode deixar o sistema operacional fazer isso sem copiar um byte sequer.

Comment: @bigown usando a própria classe File? Sinceramente eu não faço ideia de como faz, pensei que era coisa da classe Files, desse pacote novo que foi adicionado nas versões mais novas. Editei a pergunta para não se fechar apenas ao java 8 ou a classe citada.

Comment: `java.nio.file.Files` tem um `move` desde a versão 7, não serve pra você?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A primeira grande mudança a fazer é só [mover o arquivo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) e não copiá-lo, isso é um enorme desperdício de recurso. Você pode apenas pedir para o sistema operacional rearranjar sua organização do sistema de arquivos, sem sequer copiar, ou mesmo mover um *byte* dele, basta mudar os metadados dele para indicar que está em outra pasta. Não precisa saber de nada como isso funciona, basta saber qual o método chamar.

```
private static void copiarArquivos() throws IOException {
    File src = new File(".");
    String dstPath = "C:\\java\\";
    for (File f : src.listFiles()) {
        String fileName = f.getName();
        if (fileName.contains("File")) Files.move(f.toPath(), Paths.get(dstPath, fileName), REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/CopyFiles.java).

Java 8 ainda permite usar *streams* ([exemplos](https://blog.jooq.org/2014/01/10/java-8-friday-goodies-java-io-finally-rocks/)) e o código pode ficar mais declarativo. Nem sempre gosto, acho que assim é simples e compreensível.

Dá para matar duas variáveis, mas deixei.

Comment: A titulo de curiosidade, ao inves de copiar com o mesmo nome e renomear depois, posso renomear ao mover alterando dentro do `Path.get`?

Comment: Não está copiando nada, está movendo.

Comment: Então não tem problema mover com nome diferente?

Comment: Não tem problema algum. Mover significa mudar os metadados do sistema de arquivo, não mexe no conteúdo, então você muda o *path*  todo dele, não há distinção entre nome do arquivo e da pasta, o que está fazendo é trocar o nome de um objeto, parte do nome é o sobrenome dele, ou seja, é a pasta. Renomear é justamente mover, para a mesma ou outra pasta.

Comment: Só uma pequena correção(só pude testar hoje kkk), o método `move` espera 3 parametros, sendo 2 do tipo Path e um terceiro opcional do tipo `CopyOption`. Como fileName é *String*, foi necessário trocar por `f.toPath()` para funcionar corretamente.

Comment: @diegofm Verdade, eu fiz sem me atentar a esses detalhes. Estou corrigindo.

Answer (score 3):

Apenas a título de curiosidade em versões anteriores ao 7.

**Renomeando:**

```
import java.io.File;

public class Movendo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      File arquivo = new File("C:/pasta1/arquivo.txt");

      if (arquivo.renameTo(new File("C:/pastab/" + arquivo.getName()))) {
        System.out.println("Arquivo movido com sucesso!");
      } else {
        System.out.println("Falha ao mover arquivo!");
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Falha ao mover arquivo!");
    }
  }
}
```