# Fazer busca recursiva em todos os diretorios e subdiretorios de uma determinada pasta

Tags: java, arquivo, recursão

Estou desenvolvendo um script para varrer uma determinada pasta a procura de certos arquivos e excluí-los ou movê-los para outra pasta, conforme algumas regras que já obtive resposta [**nesta pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167949/28595) e [**nesta outra pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168715/28595).

Minhha idéia era em abstrair essa busca, salvando todos os arquivos encontrados(seja para mover ou para excluir) em uma lista e posteriormente tomar uma decisão quanto a operação, só que não faço muita ideia de como fazer uma busca em determinada pasta e toda sua árvore de diretórios internos que forem sendo encontrados.

```
private static List<File> listarArquivos(File source, boolean condicao) {
    List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

    File[] list = source.listFiles();

    for (File fl : list) {
        if (condicao) {
            fileList.add(fl);
            System.out.println(fl);
        }
    }

    return fileList;

}
```

Este método só lista as subpastas e arquivos do diretório principal, mas não lista arquivos e pastas mais internos, como fazer isso de forma recursiva?

<sub>*Obs.: em caso de soluções utilizando java-8, peço uma breve explicação,pois não sou muito familiarizado com as novas classes desta versão.*</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando **Java 8** você pode usar o método `walk` da classe `Files`:

```
List<Path> lista = new ArrayList<>();

Files.walk(Paths.get("C:/D/Desktop/Workshop"))
        .filter(arquivo -> this.filtrar(arquivo))
        .forEach(lista::add);
```

Ou caso queria retornar uma lista de `File`:

```
List<File> lista = new ArrayList<>();

Files.walk(Paths.get("C:/D/Desktop/Workshop"))
        .filter(arquivo -> this.filtrar(arquivo))
        .forEach(arquivo -> {
          lista.add(arquivo.toFile());
        });
```

Considerando que o método `filtrar` seja assim (baseado [**nesta resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167949/como-criar-uma-regex-para-filtrar-e-deletar-arquivos-com-determinado-trecho-no-n/167965#167965)):

```
private boolean filtrar(Path caminho) {
  return caminho.toString().matches("Copia - Copia\\.[^.]+$");
}
```

> [**Files.walk**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-)
>
> Retorna um `Stream` que `ociosamente`*(`Lazy`)* popula com `Path` percorrendo a árvore dos arquivos começando pelo arquivo inicial

Adaptando para o seu método:

```
private static List<File> listarArquivos(File source, boolean condicao) throws IOException {
  List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

  Files.walk(source.toPath()).forEach(arquivo -> {
    if (condicao) {
      fileList.add(arquivo.toFile());
    }
  });

  return fileList;
}
```

Comment: o que é esse método `filtrar`?

Comment: @renan qualquer método que possa restringir os arquivos adicionados a lista. No caso poderia ser usado o método sugerido [nesta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167949/como-criar-uma-regex-para-filtrar-e-deletar-arquivos-com-determinado-trecho-no-n) que havia sido linkada na pergunta original

Comment: Como ficaria aquele trecho inicial da resposta, retornando array de File ao inves de Path?

Comment: @diegofm adicionei na resposta

Comment: Eu não entendi esse `filtrar`, qual das respostas linkada você viu isso?

Comment: @diegofm eu coloquei um nome qualquer. Seria um método retornando `boolean` em que você faria a verificação do nome do arquivo. Se você quiser eu coloco um exemplo de como ficaria o método

Comment: @diegofm adicionei na resposta um método `filtrar` como exemplo

Comment: O problema é que se eu criar um método filtrar, vou ter que criar vários porque não é só o filtro de "copiar" que tenho. Tem outros que preciso aplicar também. O código da pergunta está adaptado para a forma tradicional das versões anteriores porque eu não fazia ideia de como usar  esses novos métodos do java8

Comment: @diegofm Você pode colocar todas as verificações no mesmo método. Mas de qualquer forma é só um exemplo de como você poderia filtrar a lista antes de colocá-la no seu retorno. Você pode remover aquela linha que adicionará todos os arquivos da árvore

Comment: Acho que entendi o funcionamento do método do final da resposta. Esse `arquivo` é uma representação do Path de cada arquivo que o forEach percorre, correto?

Comment: @diegofm exato. O `walk` retorna um `Stream` com todos os `Paths` presentes na árvore. O `forEach` percorre o `Stream` atribuindo ele a variável de qualquer nome que colocarmos no início da chamada do método. Poderia ser `f`, `a` ou qualquer coisa assim. Achei que `arquivo` ficaria mais signficativo

Answer (score 6):

É só fazer uma verificação se **`fl`** é um diretório usando [`File.isDirectory()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory()) e chamar o método novamente passando `fl` como parâmetro.

```
private static List<File> listarArquivos(File source) 
{
    List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

    File[] list = source.listFiles();

    for (File fl : list) {
        if (!fl.isDirectory()) {
            fileList.add(fl);
            System.out.println(fl);
        }else{
            System.out.println(String.format("** Pasta: %s **", fl));
            listarArquivos(fl);
        }
    }

    return fileList;
}
```