# É possivel copiar nomes de diretórios sem copiar seu conteudo?

Tags: java, arquivo

Há algum tempo eu fiz [**esta pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/169212/28595) sobre busca recursiva em pastas, e agora eu preciso adaptar para uma condição diferente.

Preciso copiar apenas os nomes das subpastas de uma pasta superior para uma terceira, mas sem copiar os arquivos e pastas mais internas, ou seja, preciso "clonar" as subpastas de primeiro nível sem levar seu conteúdo junto.

ex.:

```
-Pasta root
    |-subpasta1✅
        |-sub-subpasta1(esse nivel não pode ser copiado)
    |-subpasta2 ✅
    |-subpasta3✅
    |-subpasta4✅
    ...
    |-subpastaN✅
```

Atualmente estou utilizando um método sugerido na pergunta linkada para filtrar arquivos:

```
private static List<File> filtrarArquivos(File source, String pattern) throws IOException {
    List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

    Files.walk(source.toPath()).forEach(arquivo -> {

        if (arquivo.getFileName().toString().matches(pattern)) {
            fileList.add(arquivo.toFile());
        }
    });

    return fileList;
}
```

É possível adaptar esse método para o problema relatado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alterando o seu método você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
private static List<File> filtrarDiretorios(File origem) throws IOException {
  List<File> diretorios = new ArrayList<>();

  Files.list(origem.toPath())
          .map(arquivo -> arquivo.toFile())
          .filter(arquivo -> arquivo.isDirectory())
          .forEach(diretorios::add);

  return diretorios;
}
```

Usamos o [`Steram#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) para converter o conteúdo da lista retornada pelo [`Path#list`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#list-java.nio.file.Path-) em um `Stream` de `File`. Utilizamos o método [`Stream#filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) do `Stream` resultando para filtrar apenas os `File` que sejam um diretório com a função [`File#isDirectory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory--) e percorremos os registros resultantes com [`Stream#forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) para adicioná-los ao `List` que retornará do método `filtrarArquivos`.

Você pode aplicar o método acima da seguinte forma (Completando a copia das pastas):

```
private static void copiarDiretorios(File origem, File destino) throws IOException {
  List<File> diretorios;

  diretorios = filtrarDiretorios(origem);
  diretorios.forEach(diretorio -> copiar(destino, diretorio));
}

private static void copiar(File destino, File diretorio) {
  File novo;

  novo = new File(destino, diretorio.getName());
  novo.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: Mas ai não vai funcionar de forma recursiva, como o exemplo da pergunta? Pois o que me atrapalharia agora em copiar o primeiro nivel de  diretorios é a recursividade sair varrendo outros niveis de subpasta.

Comment: @diegofm alterado para responder sem recursividade

Comment: Adaptei de um jeito diferente mas a base eu usei o método filtrardiretorios mesmo, valeu :D

Comment: @diegofm disponha. Só uma coisa, talvez esse método de `filtrarDiretorios` pudesse retornar só um `List<String>`. Não sei se teria muito impacto essa mudança, mas acho que faz mais sentido

Comment: Eu pensei nisso também mas eu verifico umas outras coisas que pelo File  fica mais viável que String, por isso retornei File, pra facilitar.

Answer (score 3):

O seguinte método copia todos os arquivo filhos diretos de uma pasta de origem para uma pasta de destino:

```
public static final List<File> copiarSubdiretorios(File origem, File destino) throws IOException {
    List<File> arquivos = new ArrayList<>();
    for(File arquivo : origem.listFiles(File::isDirectory)) {
        File novoArquivo = new File(destino.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + arquivo.getName());
        novoArquivo.mkdirs();
        arquivos.add(novoArquivo);
    }
    return arquivos;
}
```

#### Edit:

Se você quer apenas o nome das subpastas faça o seguinte:

```
public static final List<String> listarSubdiretorios(File root) {
    return Arrays.asList(root.listFiles(File::isDirectory))
                .stream()
                .map(File::getName)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Caso você queira objetos `File` que representem as pastas:

```
public static final List<File> listarSubdiretorios(File root) {
    return Arrays.asList(root.listFiles(File::isDirectory));
}
```

Comment: Dessa forma não me serve, pois o source é o Path da pasta root, e eu não quero utilizar o mesmo método para fazer tudo. Somente receber o path da pasta root e me retornar uma lista dos diretorios de primeiro nivel pra eu criar em outra pasta, como no exemplo.

Comment: @diegofm editei a resposta.

Comment: Valeu, esse método funcionou também, só que eu já tinha aplicado o outro. Mas fica uma opção como alternativa :)